# Ruby On Rails Signup: Submitting invalid signup twice with selected "type" radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through Mhartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial on the user signup portion. I am trying to implement Single Table Inheritance, which I did by adding a type column to my BaseUser model.

On my form, I added two radio buttons for the user to specify his desired account type: Property Holder, or Service Provider.

If the user checks off one of the boxes, but makes a mistake in any of the other columns, the page will re-render. If he tries to submit again, I get the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: base_user
```

I think the reason that this is happening is because, my controller is sending a post request as a BaseUser the first time, but is sending a post request as a PropertyHolder the second time and sends "type" twice in the second request. Here is the relevant server log:

```
             "property_holder"=>{"name"=>"", 
                                 "email"=>"", 
                                 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
                                 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
                                 "type"=>"PropertyHolder"}, 
                                 "commit"=>"Create my account",
                                 "type"=>"PropertyHolder"}
```

Am I correct in my understanding of this problem? How should I go about fixing this?

First Time

```
Started POST "/base_users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-28 15:38:58 -0800
Processing by BaseUsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
               "authenticity_token"=>"+e5APfbWVfLCeqh1/n/05u49b+rKdGD1JJ9Vwga/y5T9uspUqmlCOioeCNCgs8x1A3RhJio+noxUjwYBG/jBUQ==",
               "base_user"=>{"name"=>"",
                             "email"=>"",
                             "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
                             "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
                             "type"=>"ServiceProvider"}, 
                "commit"=>"Create my account"}

(0.1ms)  begin transaction BaseUser Exists (0.2ms) SELECT  1 AS one FROM "base_users" WHERE LOWER("base_users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (5.1ms)
Rendered base_users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 92.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Second Time

```
Started POST "/property_holders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-28 14:59:19 -0800
Processing by BaseUsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
             "authenticity_token"=>"VABbJX6ubQM885FNbX5Zip9MFXmTWEb3XyKzwOYbkMZQVNFMIhF6y9SXMegzsmEZcgUbtXMSuI4vMuAD+1yaAw==", 
             "property_holder"=>{"name"=>"", 
                                 "email"=>"", 
                                 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
                                 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
                                 "type"=>"PropertyHolder"}, 
                                 "commit"=>"Create my account",
                                 "type"=>"PropertyHolder"} 

Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms


ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: base_user):
app/controllers/base_users_controller.rb:28:in `user_params'
app/controllers/base_users_controller.rb:15:in `create
```

EDIT: views/base_users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@base_user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>


        <label>
            <%= f.radio_button :type, "PropertyHolder", label: "test", class: 'form-control' %>Property Holder
        </label>

        <label>
            <%= f.radio_button :type, "ServiceProvider", label: "test", class: 'form-control' %>Service Provider
        </label>


      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your _form.html.erb

Comment: I added the base_user form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails uses record identification to identify the Object and use it decide on the params name, which url it should submit it to and which verb it should use. But using STI it would break, as STI class name changes based on the type. So in your case what we can do to ensure that the form doesn't break is to make sure that @base_user is treated as BaseUser class. To do that we use the becomes method.

```
@base_user.becomes(BaseUser)
```

So change your form to the following code.

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@base_user.becomes(BaseUser)) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
```

Comment: Yea, I just figured out that that was the issue as well, i changed my line to <%= form_for(@base_user, as: :base_user) do |f| %>